# Cannot read property 'longitude' or latitude of undefined

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I've read through several questions/answers here in stack and elsewhere, however I really can't figure out the solution to my problem.

I come across the uncaught type error inside a for loop.

Here is my code:

```
var markers = [];

var locationdata = <%=arr%>;
console.log(locationdata);
console.log(locationdata[0][1].latitude);
for (var i = 0; locationdata[0].length; i++) {
  var location = locationdata[0];
  var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(location[i].latitude, location[i].longitude);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    'position': latLng,
    'icon': image
  });
  markers.push(marker);
}
```

Before the for loop, I do a console.log which shows the correct value, I've also tried printing within the for loop and it shows the right value as well. However, when I put it the latLng var, I just seem to keep getting the undefined error. Please help, thank you!

Comment: what line of code throws the error? what do you see in browser console? Fix the `for` condition: `for (var i = 0; i  < locationdata[0].length; i++) {`

Comment: @Igor `var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(location[i].latitude, location[i].longitude);` on location[i].latitude/longitude, whichever will come first. in browser console it shows, `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'latitude' of undefined
    at initialize (facilitymaps.jsp:252)`

Comment: you let `i` value run beyond the length of `locationdata[0]` in your `for` condition

Comment: The conditional in your for loop is broken as @Igor pointed out.  That is likely causing the error.

Comment: I did not notice that AT ALL! so simple, thank you so much!

Comment: What does `locationdata` look like?  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.